# Python multiprocessing - Subprocesses with same PID

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

Basically I'm trying to open a new process every time I call a function. The problem is that when I get the PID inside of the function, the PID is the same as in another functions even if the other functions haven't finished yet.

I'm wrapping my function with a decorator:

```py
def run_in_process(function):
    """Runs a function isolated in a new process.

    Args:
        function (function): Function to execute.
    """

    def wrapper(*args):
        parent_connection, child_connection = Pipe()
        process = Process(target=function, args=(*args, child_connection))
        process.start()
        response = parent_connection.recv()
        process.join()
        return response

    return wrapper
```

And declaring the function like this:

```py
@run_in_process
def example(data, pipe):
    print(os.getpid())
    pipe.send("Just an example here!")
    pipe.close()
```

Obs1.:This code is running inside a AWS Lambda.

Obs2.: Those lambdas didn't finish before the other one starts, because this tasks takes at least 10 seconds.

[Log of execution 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MW00z.png)

[Log of execution 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CIQ07.png)

[Log of execution 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHZQ1.png)

You can see at the logs that each one is a different execution and they are executed at the "same" time.

**The question is: Why they have the same PID even knowing that they are running concurrently? Shouldn't they have different PIDs?**

I obligatorily need to execute this function in an isolated process

Answer (score 0):

Your Lambda function could have been running in multiple containers at once in the AWS cloud. If you've been heavily testing your function with multiple concurrent requests, it is quite possible that the AWS orchestration created additional instances to handle the traffic.

With serverless, you lose some of the visibility into exactly how your code is being executed, but does it really matter?

Comment: Oh, I got it. So based on the tests on my local machine, I can assure that those functions are running in a separated process? Even if the PID is the same (because they are in a different container probably)

Comment: The expectation is that running `Process.start()` in your code does indeed start a new process.  Can you be completely "assured" that those functions are running in a separate process / memory space?  I guess it depends on your definition of "assured".  By deploying as a serverless solution, you are asking AWS to control a lot of the execution details for you behind the scenes.  Personally, I am confident that your code is running in separate processes despite the PID matching.  If you need deep control over process isolation for compliance reasons, you may want to dig deeper...